# ggplot: how to "correct" an unrepresentative spike in the plot

Tags: r, time-series, data-modeling, smoothing

I have data of a percent score along datetime (date and hours:minutes:seconds). I want to graphically "correct"/highlight a data point that isn't representative.

### Background

I have data about how people rate their happiness level on a daily basis, on a continuous scale running 0 -> 1, where 0 means "extremely unhappy" and 1 means "extremely happy". I ask many people and want to get a sense of "happiness in the group" over time.

### Data

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1234)

original_df <- 
  seq(as.POSIXct('2020-09-01', tz = "UTC"), as.POSIXct('2020-09-15', tz = "UTC"), by="1 mins") %>%
  sample(15000, replace = T) %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  rename(date_time = value) %>%
  mutate(date = date(date_time)) %>%
  add_column(score = runif(15000))

original_df

## # A tibble: 15,000 x 3
##  date_time           date       score
##    <dttm>              <date>     <dbl>
##  1 2020-09-06 04:11:00 2020-09-06 0.683
##  2 2020-09-06 13:35:00 2020-09-06 0.931
##  3 2020-09-05 23:21:00 2020-09-05 0.121
##  4 2020-09-06 14:45:00 2020-09-06 0.144
##  5 2020-09-07 09:15:00 2020-09-07 0.412
##  6 2020-09-01 10:22:00 2020-09-01 0.564
##  7 2020-09-11 14:00:00 2020-09-11 0.960
##  8 2020-09-08 13:24:00 2020-09-08 0.845
##  9 2020-09-01 15:33:00 2020-09-01 0.225
## 10 2020-09-09 19:27:00 2020-09-09 0.815
## # ... with 14,990 more rows
```

#### However, it turns out that one of the days happens to have substantially fewer data points. Thus, the actual data set looks like the following:

```r
actual_df <- 
  original_df %>%
  filter(date %in% as_date("2020-09-10")) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 15) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  bind_rows(original_df %>% filter(!date %in% as_date("2020-09-10")))

> actual_df %>% count(date)

## # A tibble: 14 x 2
##    date           n
##    <date>     <int>
##  1 2020-09-01  1073
##  2 2020-09-02  1079
##  3 2020-09-03  1118
##  4 2020-09-04  1036
##  5 2020-09-05  1025
##  6 2020-09-06  1089
##  7 2020-09-07  1040
##  8 2020-09-08  1186
##  9 2020-09-09  1098
## 10 2020-09-10    15 ## <- this day has less data 
## 11 2020-09-11  1095
## 12 2020-09-12  1051
## 13 2020-09-13  1037
## 14 2020-09-14  1034
```

### Plotting this data over time

#### What I've been doing relies on working with means

I treat every day as a factor, and get the daily mean. Statistically, this solution might be far from ideal, as @BrianLang commented below. However, right now this is the method I chose.

```r
library(emmeans)

model_fit <- 
  actual_df %>%
  mutate(across(date, factor)) %>%
  lm(score ~ date, data = .)

emmeans_fit_data <- emmeans(model_fit, ~ date, CIs = TRUE)

emmeans_fit_data %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = date, y = emmean)) +
  geom_line(color = "#1a476f", group = 1, lwd = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower.CL, ymax = upper.CL), alpha = 0.5, color = "#90353b", width = 0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(100*emmean, 1), "%") , color = "90353b"), vjust = -4, hjust = 0.5, size = 3.5) +
  geom_point(color = "1a476f") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(100*x, "%")) +
  ylab("Level of Happiness") +
  xlab("Date") +
  ggtitle("Mood Over Time") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -60, hjust = 0),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 8),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]


But then I get this spike on 2020-09-10, which is only due to low number of data points.
One graphical solution would be to do something like dashing the problematic line and "completing" how it would've looked like with enough data points. Perhaps based on averaging the day before and the day after? I don't want to get rid of the real data, but do want to graphically highlight that this is unrepresentative, and that the real value should have been much closer to the day before & after. I was thinking that using dashed lines is a reasonable graphical solution. 
[image: dashed]

Otherwise, I was hoping that there could be a different method for modeling/plotting such "by-time" data using `ggplot`'s smoothing, that will give me a smoother trend line and a confidence ribbon that will account for the problematic day. But I understand that it might be beyond the scope of this question, so I'm just adding it as a side note; in case someone wants to suggest a solution based on different modeling, instead of a mere graphical correction. But I will be thankful for either.

Comment: It seems that you fit this model with data as a categorical. I think you should probably be treating date as a continuous variable. Your issue is that you do not understand the data you have or the models that would be appropriate to fit on the data. For this you need to learn about models, potentially arima models.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my question is certainly due to lack of knowledge, which I'm hoping to get by the question I posted. Could you possibly elaborate or direct me further? ARIMA models is one type I wasn't aware of. Anything else you could think of? I can google things free-style, but this is what I had been doing before posting here, so I need some more focus. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without wanting to get into time-series models, you could imagine transforming your time variable with restricted cubic splines.

I needed to change a bit of your code so I could avoid installing the newest versions of some packages ;-).

Notice that I changed some variable names because `date` is a function name, and shouldn't be used as also a variable name.

```r
library(chron)

## added a numeric version of your date variable.
actual_df <- original_df %>%
 filter(datez %in% lubridate::date("2020-09-10")) %>%
 sample_n(size = 15) %>%
 group_by(datez) %>%
 ungroup %>%
 bind_rows(original_df %>% filter(!datez %in% lubridate::date("2020-09-10"))) %>%
 mutate(num_date = as.numeric(datez))
```

```r
## How many knots across the dates do you want?
number_of_knots = 15

## This is to make sure that visreg is passed the actual knot locations! RMS::RCS does not store them in the model fits. 
knots <- paste0("c(", paste0(attr(rms::rcs(actual_df$num_date, number_of_knots), "parms"), collapse = ", "), ")") 

## We can construct the formula early.
formula <- as.formula(paste("score ~ rms::rcs(num_date,", knots,")"))

## fit the model as a gaussian glm and pass it to visreg for it's prediction function. This will give you predicted means and 95% CI for that mean. Then I convert the numeric dates back to real dates. 
glm_rcs <- glm(data = actual_df, formula = formula, family = "gaussian") %>% visreg::visreg(plot = F) %>% .$fit %>%
 mutate(date_date = chron::as.chron(num_date) %>% as.POSIXct())

## plot it!
ggplot(data = glm_rcs, aes(date_date,
                           y = visregFit)) + 
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = visregLwr, ymax = visregUpr), alpha = .5) +
 geom_line()
```

[image: The plotted figure after smoothing with RCS]

---

EDIT: You collect the data by day, but you could add jitter to the date such that they get spread out over the day.

```r
actual_df <- original_df %>%
 filter(datez %in% lubridate::date("2020-09-10")) %>%
 sample_n(size = 15) %>%
 group_by(datez) %>%
 ungroup %>%
 bind_rows(original_df %>% filter(!datez %in% lubridate::date("2020-09-10"))) %>%
 mutate(num_date = as.numeric(datez))  %>%
## Here we add random noise (uniform -.5 to .5) to each numeric date.
 mutate(jittered_date = num_date + runif(n(), -.5, .5))

## You can lower this number to increase smoothing.
number_of_knots = 15

knots <- paste0("c(", paste0(attr(rms::rcs(actual_df$jittered_date, number_of_knots), "parms"), collapse = ", "), ")")

formula <- as.formula(paste("score ~ rms::rcs(jittered_date,", knots,")"))

glm_rcs <- glm(data = actual_df, formula = formula, family = "gaussian") %>% visreg::visreg(plot = F) %>% .$fit %>%
 mutate(date_date = chron::as.chron(jittered_date) %>% as.POSIXct())

ggplot(data = glm_rcs, aes(date_date,
                           y = visregFit)) +
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = visregLwr, ymax = visregUpr), alpha = .5) +
 geom_line()
```

[image: figure after adding jitter to dates]

---

Edit 2:

The jittering of points isn't *as* necessary if you have a datetime vector rather than a simple day.
In your original code to create the fake data you use `lubridate::date()`, which takes your posix datetime vector and strips to down to a simple date! You can avoid this with something like this:

```r
original_df <- tibble(datez = seq(as.POSIXct('2020-09-01', tz = "UTC"), as.POSIXct('2020-09-15', tz = "UTC"), by="1 mins") %>%
 sample(15000, replace = T)) %>%
 mutate(datez_day = lubridate::date(datez)) %>%
 add_column(score = runif(15000))

actual_df <- original_df %>%
 filter(datez_day %in% lubridate::date("2020-09-10")) %>%
 sample_n(size = 15) %>%
 bind_rows(original_df %>% filter(!datez_day %in% lubridate::date("2020-09-10"))) %>%
 mutate(num_date = as.numeric(datez))
```

now you have `datez_day` which is the day value, `datez` which is a datetime, and `num_date` which is a numeric representation of the datetime.

from there you can directly model on `num_date` without adding any jitter.

```r
number_of_knots = 20

knots <- paste0("c(", paste0(attr(rms::rcs(actual_df$num_date, number_of_knots), "parms"), collapse = ", "), ")")

formula <- as.formula(paste("score ~ rms::rcs(num_date,", knots,")"))

glm_rcs <- glm(data = actual_df, formula = formula, family = "gaussian") %>% 
        visreg::visreg(plot = F) %>% 
        .$fit %>% 
        as_tibble() %>%
   ## Translate the num_date back into a datetime object so it is correct in the figures!
        mutate(date_date = as.POSIXct.numeric(round(num_date), origin = "1970/01/01"))

ggplot(data = glm_rcs, aes(date_date,
                           y = visregFit)) +
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = visregLwr, ymax = visregUpr), alpha = .5) +
 geom_line()
```

Comment: This is very helpful. However, in my real data (not the one simulated for the question), I end up with a stronger dip than what shown in your solution. (see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNQ3B.png) While this obviously has to do with differences between datasets, and without seeing the real data, could you hypothesize why it's giving such a dominant dip?

Comment: It actually brings up the question I raised in the post. If I have such a dominant dip that is clearly due to low number of data points in a given time, then how can I address that in case the smoothing doesn't smooth it away? The motivation for solving this problem comes from the need to communicate the plot to others. I want people seeing the plot for the first time will not be distracted or misled by such a dip. So either I correct this cosmetically/graphically, or with smoothing methodology.

Comment: You can vary the number of knots if you'd like. Lowering this number will make the relationship be estimated with fewer degrees of freedom, increasing the smoothing.

Comment: I thought about it a bit more. You have all the data weight specifically on the x values as days. If you add jitter to the dates such that they span the entire day, we can have more smooth fits.

Comment: I see. But if we consider that the data *did* have time as continuous datetime, and wasn't hardcoded by days? Weighting by days was a choice, but could it been done otherwise? Is it possible to model the data with X as a continuous time flow and later mark plot segments as days?

Comment: Yeah, certainly. If you data is already continuous time you don't need to add jitter. You just need to figure out how R works with dates (good luck!). For most models, you'll want to work with the dates as a numeric vector, then switch them back after your prediction step (which is what smooths your data). I'll add a bit for a final edit on the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222290/discussion-between-brianlang-and-emman).